# Implement agregation in cooja

Tags: aggregation, contiki, cooja, sensors

Could someone has an idea on how to implement agregation in udp-client.c with cooja Please? I have a linear network with one server (node 1) and 4 clients running on contiki. 1 is connected to 2 which is connected to 3 which is connected to 4 which is connected to 5. My goal is that node2 wait for the data from node3 before sending its data to node1, node3 waits for the data from node4 and node4 waits for the data from node5 before sending to node3. 
I am using cooja.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To define the link between the different nodes, you use the Directed Graph Radio Medium (DGRM) "DGRM" mode to specify link quality between the node1 and the node2 , node2 and node3 ..etc, in order to create a linear topology for your network.

You can modify the code executed by your node (udp-client.c) to send specific msgs.
when a msg is received, the node witch receive the msg verify that it was sent by the parent so it will send the msg for its children.